# Eclipse PDT auto implementing interface methods

Tags: php, eclipse, interface, code-generation, eclipse-pdt

I have some PHP interface with defined methods.

Is there a way to auto-generate all interface methods in class that implements it in eclipse?
(if there are other free solutions for eclipse PHP development (except PDT) I'm opened for suggestions)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using NetBeans since 2010 and they support this.  Under Source > Insert Code.  I haven't used PDT in a while, so I can't help you there.

Comment: Well entire team in company where I work is using eclipse, so switching to NetBeans is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Add the PDT Extensions plugin for Eclipse.

Go to `Help -> Install New Software ->` add url: `"http://p2.pdt-extensions.org" -> select PDT Extensions` from the list